# Updating java start.sh script upon updating from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, sh

Here is my current script http://pastebin.com/jHpr2hvc Since updating from Java 7 to 8 I get a lot of warnings, it still works but many warnings appear and are quite clustered upon launching the script. I use this script to start my Minecraft server.

Could someone edit or give me advice on editing the script so that I can still assign the memory in a similar and make it so the script still restarts/loops, but can stop errors like in the pastebin below from appearing. Thanks

Here is some of the errors i am getting: http://pastebin.com/1uAT8z0n

Comment: Please include the relevant portion of the script and the error output directly in your question.

Comment: A popular phrase of a friend of mine is; "every time you add a JVM tuning argument, a puppy dies."  I suggest you do the absolute minimum options. i.e. start with none and only add the ones you really, really need.  When I start spigot, I just use the `-jar` option. Many of the options either don't do anything or could be causing more harm than good.

Comment: Minecraft needs to update their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are apparently caused by this bug in Java 8 / Java 9:

- http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8046668

Suppressing all JNI warnings (remove "-Xcheck:jni") should work as a temporary workaround.

A better solution would be to try to upgrade to a Java 8 version that has the bug fixed.  If I have interpreted the bug reports correctly, the fix was made in Java 9 and backported to Java 8 u60 and later.

Answer (score 1):

From [this Oracle documentation](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3783234?start=0&tstart=0), it appears that the warning messages are being caused by this JVM parameter:

```
-Xcheck:jni
```

> So warnings produced by -Xcheck:jni were added with the JNI Specification in mind, allowing users to find potential problems even when switching JVM implementations.

Assuming your code still runs, removing this parameter from your `start.sh` script should make the warnings go away.